# How to print out highlighted text in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I was wondering if there is a way to print out highlighted text in eclipse by using shortcuts.

So say we had

```
 int number = 2;
 number //highlight number + some key combination to turn -> System.out.println(number);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select `number`, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, type `syso` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The trick is to trigger the content assist (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) when something is selected and then type the beginning of the template (in this case `syso`) and not the other way around (not `syso` and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>).

See [this @EclipseJavaIDE tip](https://twitter.com/EclipseJavaIDE/status/1054290293347049473):

[image]